# AJAX sending POST request and asp.net receiving GET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

Halo, Im doing my cs project for school in web service using asp.net, c#. Im having a problem that when Im sending an AJAX POST request Im receiving a GET request, I couldnt find the problem myself pls help :)

I tried to send an AJAX POST request when a textbox is being changed to the backend to write the textbox to a file, but when Im doing Request.HttpMethod Im getting a GET request.

this is my html code:

```
<%@ Page Async="true" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FilePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="filmhelperschoolproject.Pages.FilePage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <center>
        <form runat="server" id="form1">
            <div>
            <textarea style="width:40%; height:800px;" runat="server" id="fileTextArea" oninput= "saveText()"></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
        
    </center>
</body>
    <script>
        function saveText() {
            event.preventDefault();
            var url_string = window.location.href;
            var url = new URL(url_string);
            var name = url.searchParams.get("name");
            var id = url.searchParams.get("id");
            var filename = name + id;
            var text = document.getElementById('fileTextArea').value;
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "FilePage.aspx?id=" + id + "&name=" + name,
                data: {
                    "text": "hello world"
                },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('File written successfully!');
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    console.log('Error writing file: ' + error);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

and this is my Page_Load function:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name = Request.QueryString["name"];
            string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
            string path = "C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\filmhelperschoolproject\\filmhelperschoolproject\\Files\\";
            if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
            {

                string text = Request.Form["text"];
                File.WriteAllText(path + name + id + ".txt", text);
                return;

            }
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                fileTextArea.InnerText = "";


                string [] lines=File.ReadAllLines(path + name + id + ".txt");
                foreach( string line in lines)

                {
                    fileTextArea.InnerText += line + "\n";
                }

            }
            
        }
```

pls help :)

(P.S  u look very nice today sir! )

Comment: `$(function () { $("#formID").on("submit", (e) => { e.preventdefault(); var url_string = window.location.href; var url = new URL(url_string); .....})})` or `$(function () { $("#fieldID").on("change", (e) => { e.preventdefault(); var url_string = window.location.href; var url = new URL(url_string); .....})})` - show your HTML and how you call the function for better help

Answer (score 0):

You should use : `dataType: "json"` .
And check the official documentation for jquery ajax [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the complete guide.